# Storing notes or a history in a database and displaying them in swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I was hoping someone could have a quick look at how I'm thinking of approaching a feature in a program I'm making. It allows you to add people, via a JPanel, to a database, which is summarised in an adjacent JTable.

Clicking on any of the rows provides a more detailed view of each person in a panel below. I'd like to add the functionality to allow the user to type notes about the person and have them dated and stored in the database.

My idea

When each person is added to the database the program creates a folder with their id number. inside the folder is a text document. adding text to the JTextPanel retrieves the selectedrow in the jtable and finds the relevant folder and text file. Either that or I could have an actual address saved as a column in the database. Clicking save adds the date and time to this text file along with the notes and some form of delimiter. Additionally, clicking any other row will read the corresponding file and display their notes. This does definitely seem like it will involve a lot of redundancy - rereading and writing old notes, but as it's only text and not a massive program I'm not sure if this is a problem.

I don't know if this is a good approach, maybe I've overlooked something, but I think using folders fits with the additional requirement of needing a word document (a person's CV) linked to the database entry for the person. It would also make me learn about how java deals with directories and files, which I'm not hugely experienced with.

I'd really appreciate people's input, as I'm sure I could be looking at this in a really inefficient way! Thanks

Comment: This Question is too broad for Stack Overflow. This site is aimed at narrowly focused questions dealing with a specific programming issue, and seeks to avoid wide-ranging discussions.

Comment: i appreciate that, but is this not quite a specific question in terms of design? it is a pretty narrow programming issue, at least from my perspective. apologies if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to store the notes in a database, and then start talking about storing in local files. So your intended solution isn't clear. Why not just store the notes in the DB itself as a CLOB? Or if you have a note length limit you could use a lvarchar sized properly.

If you really want to go the local route then the Java Prefences API would probably work well, it would handle all reading/writing to a local location.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/

Comment: It was from a lack of knowledge rather than anything else. Thought it better to at least have put some thought into it before asking 'how', even if it was a bad way of approaching it. Thanks for the quick response, I'll look into doing it that way now.